# How to transform (or possibly pivot) these MySQL results into a consolidated view?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pivot, pivot-table

The result of a MySQL query look like this:

```
key | name | value
----+------+--------
1   | foo  | alpha
1   | bar  | beta
2   | foo  | charlie
2   | bar  | delta
3   | foo  | echo
```

How can I transform the result into this?

```
key | foo     | bar
----+---------+--------
1   | alpha   | beta
2   | charlie | delta
3   | echo    |
```

I would prefer a SQL solution, but the result is being passed into PHP so I could manipulate the result using PHP if there is no SQL solution. I am reluctant to use PHP however as I have a feeling it will be very slow for queries where there may be a thousand or more different values in the `key` column.

I have heard the term pivoting being used when I searched for an answer on Google. I don't fully understand what that means though so I'm not sure if pivoting is relevant here.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It would be far more scalable and flexible to do this in PHP. So, I don't understand your reluctance.

Comment: try Case or Decode sql function

Comment: @Strawberry I don't doubt it would be more scalable and flexible in PHP, but I think it would be slower. Scalability, flexibility and speed (though related) are not the same. Speed is my key driver in this instance.

Comment: @Avi Thank you, I will research those functions.

Comment: @OhFiddyYouSoWiddy If the result is being passed to PHP anyway, then I suspect that your concerns are unfounded. However, if I'm wrong, then in my experience, a series of LEFT JOINs will (very) fractionally outperform GL's suggestion.

Comment: @Strawberry My feelings may be unfounded then. Thank you for your contribution, I will run some tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select `key`,
       max(case when name = 'foo' then value end) as foo,
       max(case when name = 'bar' then value end) as bar
from t
group by `key`;
```

If you have multiple values for each `key`, then `group_concat()` might be more appropriate than `max()`.

If you don't know the list of possible names, then Google "MySQL dynamic pivot" for examples of what to do.  That requires using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will test this out.

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. I have added my own answer as a record for other people, but of course your answer gets accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Although Gordon Linoff's solution was the accepted answer I have decided to add an example of how I implemented it. This should help anyone who stumbles across this question in the future!

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE `items` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`uuid` INT NOT NULL,
`key` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`value` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

-- insert some rows
INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `uuid`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('1', '1', 'name', 'Foo');
INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `uuid`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('2', '1', 'price', '100');
INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `uuid`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('3', '2', 'name', 'Bar');
INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `uuid`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('4', '2', 'price', '200');
INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `uuid`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('5', '3', 'name', 'Baz');

-- and fetch them
SELECT `uuid`,
MAX(IF((`key` = 'name'), `value`, NULL)) AS `name`,
MAX(IF((`key` = 'price'), `value`, NULL)) AS `price`
FROM `items`
GROUP BY `uuid`;
```